# checking which callback is executed in the page load

Tags: callback, devexpress, panel

I have two aspxcallbackpanels with two different callback functions. Is there a way to check on Page_Load which one of them is being executed?

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze the **ASPxCallbackInstance.IsCallback** property to determine whether or not a particular callback control is in the callback mode.